# Could someone review my post regarding product data?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I have a question about my Super User post: [How does the WD_BLACK SN770 2TB connected to PCI 3.0 NVMe 1.3 compare to the Samsung EVO 970 Plus 2TB SSD? Heat, power at idle, speed at 80% full?](https://superuser.com/questions/1768229/how-does-compare-wd-sn770-2tb-connected-to-pci-3-0-nvme-1-3-like-heat-and-power)

I'm not looking for a shopping recommendation, but for the data I explicitly asked for, i.e.

- Does the sn770 run in a pci3.0 with nvme1.3?
- What is the idle power consumption?
- How to interpret the odd graphs at random 4k access iops, is explicitly first: would that affect my usecase? Second: would a graph like the Samsung Evo 970 plus 2tb shows (and actually all 2tb m2 SSD above the sn770 price) be better when interpreting it for such a usecase?

Maybe unlucky long question style, but why close immediately?

Comment: Your question is a combination of too broad and opinion based.

Comment: Some of your questions are answered by the specification documentation. Reddit also already answered your question